# How should I adapt class for testability in python?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I've got a class, that manages some process.

dataset_processor.py

```
class DatasetProcessor:
    def __init__(path, list_element):
        self.path = path
        self.list_element = list_element

    def do_check_dirs_under_paths():
        "gets dirs from path and checks if elements are also in list_element"
```

But now, when it comes to `dataset_processor.ut.py` where I want to make unit tests and keep it independent, I should mock dirs from the path (should I?).

```
    def test_1(self):
        test_1_processor = DatasetProcessor(path='M:/example', list_element=['foo', 'bar'])
        test_1_processor.do_check_dirs_under_paths()
        self.assertTrue(test_1_processor.everything_is_ok())
```

I was considering:

1. Making another function, eg. `def mock(dirs=[])` and use special mock variables in `do_check_dirs_under_paths` function and check if `self.mock_dirs`. It affects readability but is easy to implement.
2. Build `test_params={}` argument for `do_check_dirs_under_paths`, where I would put outer data - it also affects readability.
3. Somehow shadow os.listdir, os.isdir and functions for the time of tests to manipulate results - I think that would be best option.
4. For a time of test: actually, make those dirs. Yet, since this approach might not work later (for big files, etc.) - I wanted to be consistent and sure I won't get into a bigger architecture trap later.

**@edit**

For a wider perspective. DatasetProcessor is a bigger class that manages other subprocesses of maintaining images dataset. It also checks files readaibility and generates NumPy array from images in a format I want.

The presented fragment is one of those I want to get under unit tests.

Comment: You haven't described much of what you're really trying to do, but it looks like your method should return a bool rather than being side-effective. It's actually not all that clear why you are using a class here instead of just a function.

Comment: @JaredSmith - I've put some more information. Thank You. Even those dir checks are part of a bigger process. I search for a way to test class/method activity (env-independent) even if the whole process would be done in __init__.

Comment: Everybody has there own take on testing. Personally, I generally don't side-effects in unit tests. My code that manipulates data is agnostic to the source: it could come from a file, or a socket, or POST, or be constructed purely for testing. You aren't doing any data manipulation here. The only thing I would test is feeding it a non-existent directory and a file path to make sure it raises an appropriate exception for those cases, and an empty directory (created solely for the test) to make sure it handles that edge case.

Comment: The example you have shown is quite confusing for me.  Which method from your example do you really want to test with your test code?  And, the test case seems to be a failure case rather than a success case, but still your test expects that `everything_is_ok`.  I suggest that you make it clear, what you actually want to achieve.